# How to use academic titles in the beginning of a paper

Tags: style, academic-writing

Should I use titles e.g. Dr., PhD, MS., BS, etc the beginning of a paper along with author names? Does the rule, if any, differ for different styles e.g. APA, MLA, etc.? Is the following, to make things clearer a bit, correct?

> John Doe*
>   *MS. Student for physical education, Faculty of Physical Education, Monsters University, X City, X country
>
> Dr John Doe**
>   **Assistant professor, Faculty of PE, Monsters University, X City, X Country

Answer (score 2):

In APA use the name and institution only, no titles, no functions.

Your example would read:

> John Doe*
>   * Faculty of Physical Education, Monsters University, X City, X country
>
> John Doe**
>   ** Faculty of PE, Monsters University, X City, X Country

Comment: Also, I don't know how native speakers feel about this but to me Jane and John Doe are anonymous dead people. In examples for living persons I would use a different last name such as Smith.